# Groups and primitive roots

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I prove that $48$ belongs to the group $Z_{385} ^*$? and then how do I find the order of $48$ in this group?

I just need some guidance I have no idea what to use in here.

Comment: You can show that 48 is coprime to 385 by checking that every prime divisor of 48 does not divide 385. To find its order, I suspect the Chinese Remainder Theorem would help make the numbers smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically $48$ does not belong to the group, since $48$ is a number, and the group consists of equivalence classes of numbers modulo $48$. But if we are wiling to be a little sloppy, the question is whether $48$ and $385$ are relatively prime. They are.

We have $385=5\cdot 7\cdot 11$. The group is not cyclic. This is a consequence of the general theorem that the only odd numbers that have primitive roots are the powers of primes. So $48$ could not be a generator, there is **no** generator. Soon we will find that actually $48$ has order $20$ modulo $385$.

To find the order of $48$, we may have to compute a bit. Note that $\varphi(5)=4$, $\varphi(7)=6$, and $\varphi(11)=10$. So $48^4\equiv 1\pmod{5}$, $48^6\equiv 1\pmod{7}$, and $48^{10}\equiv 1\pmod{11}$, all by Fermat's Theorem.

Thus if $k$ is the lcm of $4$, $6$, and $10$, then $48^k\equiv 1$ modulo $5$, $7$, and $11$, and hence modulo $385$.

This lcm is $60$. So the order of $48$ divides $60$. There are too many divisors of $60$, so let's see whether we can save some work. But note that $60$ is already a big improvement on the $\varphi(385)=240$ of Euler's Theorem.

The rest of the post arrives at a **quick answer**, with minimal computation.

Note that $48\equiv -1\pmod{7}$. So actually $48$ has order $2$ modulo $7$. It follows that the order of $48$ modulo $385$ must divide $20$. Much better!

Modulo $5$, we have that $48$ is congruent to $3$, which has order $4$ modulo $5$. So $4$ must divide the order of $48$ modulo $385$.

We have $48\equiv 4\pmod{11}$. Since $2^5\equiv -1\pmod{11}$, the order of $4$ modulo $11$ is $5$.

So $4$ and $5$ must each divide the order of $48$ modulo $385$, and hence the order is $20$.

Answer (score 1):

If that means the group of units in $\mathbb{Z}_{385}$, 48 is a unit if $\gcd(48, 385) = 1$. To prove $a$ is not a primitive root, its order modulo 385 must divide the order of the group, that is $\phi(385)$. So you try $a^{\phi(385) / d} \bmod 385$ for each prime divisor $d$ of $\phi(385)$, if any turn out 1, it isn't a primitive root.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Check that $\gcd(48, 385)=1$. Find the order of $48$ for each prime power dividing $385$, then take the lcm.